# Problem recording video with audio from usb soundcard using avconv

Tags: video, camera

What I'm trying to accomplish in this program is that when video and sound is captured, the output file is .mp4 extension (or some other, like .ogv),
with video and sound. I know how to capture video from raspberry pi camera, and I know how to capture sound through ALSA, By using the following line

```
raspivid -t 0 -fps 25 -o - -h 480 -w 640 | avconv -i pipe: -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:0,0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict experimental test.mp4
```

I get output with no error with file size same as generated by recording video using raspivid, but when I play using omcplayer or vlc it doesn't play just shows 1st frame for less than a second. Everything is working fine like recording audio and video separately.

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the avconv that comes with current Raspbian is ancient/obsolete/broken. Downloading a fresh copy of ffmpeg and compiling it worked for most people, including me. :)